# How to bring back files that are deleted from trash? [without using external software]

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup, catalina, trash

I have an external hard drive that contained some folders and I had permanently deleted that by mistake. Is there any way I can get that folder back?

MacOS Version: Catalina 10.15.5
Disk Drive: Transcend

I have tried software like Disk Drill, AnyRecover, iBoySoft and other types of similar software and none of them are legit. So please don't recommend such type of software. And the backup on Apple Time Machine has not been done for this device.

Comment: No backup and Disk Drill etc did not work then take it to a recovery company, but be prepared to pay... is it worth it?

Comment: Define "legit" - (& I don't mean by expanding it to 'legitimate')

Comment: Disk Drill asks me to upgrade to restore all my files and it only has an extract limit of like 500MB. This folder is 90GB in size. AnyRecover repeatedly crashes while running the scan and randomly asks for my email to enquire more about this issue. iBoySoft asks me to upgrade to their premium version to restore the files that were found. All of these kinds of software just seem like a scam.

Comment: [DiskDrill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/data-recovery-software.html) is no scam. I've paid for it and used it to recover a client's research data. The 500MB recovery is for the FREE version. If you want to recover more with DiskDrill, you've got to pay for it.

Comment: Disk Drill didn't even restore the 500 MB of files properly. All the files were overwritten. Maybe it's just some issue with the version I installed.

Comment: ahh, so your definition of 'legit' is… free?

Comment: no, it's not....

Comment: Basically, any recovery software is going to scavenge what it can find of old allocation 'logs' & attempt to extract the areas on the disk those 'logs' point to. Any write operations performed by that disk since deletion will reduce your chances of recovery. The more full or more fragmented the disk, the slower & less certain the task becomes too.